# Can Endermen be caught with a reuseable safari net?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

After reading on the [Auto Spawner entry in the Technic wiki](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Auto-Spawner), I've considered creating an Enderman spawner. However, from the [Minecraft wiki's Enderman entry](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderman):

> arrows, snowballs, eggs, and negative splash potions will not hit them due to the fact that they teleport away before impact

Is it possible, given the above, to capture an Enderman in a reusable safari net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Right click it with a reusable safari net, the launcher is only needed for mobs with a right click interface, such as villagers.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Safari Net (Reusable)](http://wiki.technicpack.net/Safari_Net_%28Reusable%29) entry of the Technic Wiki:

> The Safari Net (Reusable) is used to capture any mob for carrying in your inventory, and later placing elsewhere, similar to spawn eggs. **If the mob you intend to capture has a right-click action (like villagers) the net must be fired with a Safari Net Launcher** to capture the mob. Once a mob is captured in it, you can use the Safari Net (Reusable) in an Auto-Spawner to produce copies of the captured mob.

emphasis mine. For all other mobs, right-clicking with the net captures the mob, without the need for the launcher.